# Corda Springboot Webserver executable Jar creation

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, corda

I have followed example "joeldudleyr3/spring-observable-stream" at [enter link description here](https://github.com/joeldudleyr3/spring-observable-stream). Currently springboot server is running through tasks, how to convert it into executable jar... Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

To create a ‘fully executable’ jar with Gradle, use the following plugin configuration:

```
bootJar {
    launchScript()
}
```

See [Installing Spring Boot Applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-install) for more info.

Comment: Its giving error "Could not find method bootJar() for arguments [build_71d98a99mxj62gjwla5suorod$_run_closure2@5b1183c6]"

Comment: According to this [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#scratch) you have to use [spring-boot-gradle-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/) to build a Jar. Can you try it?